# Android / PocketSphinx: listener goes in standby a while after screen goes off

Tags: android, android-service, cmusphinx, android-wake-lock, pocketsphinx-android

I made a simple app that responds to vocal commands using PocketSphinx to understand commands and standard Google's library to speak, in a sort of conversation.

It's working well but I have a problem and I'm unable to undesrtand what's happen: after the screen goes off, but maybe it happens also after a while, without talking for a while, when the screen is on but opening another app, the application stops retrieving my vocal commands.

When I unblock the phone and/or return to the application, everything restart to work without problem.

I need that this application works in the same manner also when the phone is in standby, but I can't understand what could be the best solution (the best or simply the possible one):

- does using wakelock could change something?
- does transorming the activity in a service could be the solution?

I tried to disable battery optimization too, and also I tried with an exernal application to impose PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to mantain the CPU on, but nothing change.

Does someone has got some experience in this case and can explain me how to do?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Wakelock should do. Service probably too. It would be interesting to try and check.

Comment: I tried with separate service, with wakelock... nothing to do! I'm really desperate for that. It's really a huge issue for my app...